# By what means or mechanism did Noah find חן favor/grace in Genesis 6:8?

Tags: genesis, faith, noah, grace

It states that Noah found **חן** which is either translated in English as favor or grace, how did Noah find it? By extension how can we find it?

> “But Noah found favor/grace in the eyes of the Lord.”
> ‭‭Genesis‬ ‭6:8‬

Would it be a stretch to draw on a NT passage that says it’s by faith?

> “That is why it depends on faith, in order that the promise may rest on grace and be guaranteed to all his offspring”
> ‭‭Romans‬ ‭4:16‬ ‭

Finding grace seems important

> “Let us then with confidence draw near to the throne of grace, that we may receive mercy and **find grace** to help in time of need.”
> ‭‭Hebrews‬ ‭4:16‬

So I ask again by what mechanism is grace found, be it Noah OT, Mary NT, or be it ourselves present day?

Comment: I don't particular care if you want to insist on having the faith and grace tags, but it is not right to remove the genesis and noah tags.

Answer (score 1):

I think this part from [this answer](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/53574/39547) is really the only answer needed:

> "Thus, Noah finding grace was because he was prepared to find it and not repudiate divine favor by wicked conduct. Rom 1:18-22 discusses this same effect; specifically v18-20 says:
> The wrath of God is being revealed from heaven against all the godlessness and wickedness of men who suppress the truth by their wickedness. For what may be known about God is plain to them, because God has made it plain to them. For since the creation of the world God’s invisible qualities, His eternal power and divine nature, have been clearly seen, being understood from His workmanship, so that men are without excuse"

Answer (score 1):

> But Noah found grace in the eyes of the LORD. These are the generations of Noah: Noah was a just man and perfect in his generations, and Noah walked with God. (Genesis 6:8-9) [KJV]

One could say that **because** he was just, and perfect, and walked with God, Noah found grace in the eyes of the LORD. Here the emphasis is on walking with God. Grace was not actively sought: it was the result of walking with God.

On the other hand, the more Biblically correct view of both man and God is to place the emphasis on **seeking** grace from the LORD. In this case, because Noah sought grace from the LORD, he found it and it was by grace Noah was a just man, perfect in his generation and walked with God.

In addition to better describing God's character and man's response to a world filled with evil, I believe there are two other reasons why this second understanding is preferred. First, that is the literal meaning and sequence of the text. Noah found grace because he sought it from the LORD, not from other men, and he found what he was looking for. Thus, Noah was a preacher of righteousness ([2 Peter 2:5](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20Peter%202%3A5&version=KJV)) because he told others to seek the same grace he found.

A second reason is Noah is written "nh" and grace is "hn." That is, when "nh" looked into the eyes of the LORD, he saw his reflection, "hn." As David would later write:

> One thing have I desired of the LORD, that will I seek after; that I may dwell in the house of the LORD all the days of my life, to behold the beauty of the LORD, and to enquire in his temple. (Psalm 27:4)

The beauty of the LORD is His grace to man which for Noah, was literally seeing a mirror image of his name in the eyes of the LORD.

Answer (score 0):

To answer this question I would observe several things:

1. The book of Genesis is naturally divided into 11 "toledoths" (see appendix 1 below) and Gen 6:8 is the last and concluding verse of the toldeoth of Adam.  The thrust of Gen 6:8 is to contrast the righteous life and conduct of Noah compared to the wicked lives of his contemporaries.  Note the text of Gen 6:5-8

> Then the LORD saw that the wickedness of man was great upon the earth,
> and that every inclination of the thoughts of his heart was altogether
> evil all the time. And the LORD regretted that He had made man on the
> earth, and He was grieved in His heart. So the LORD said, “I will
> blot out man, whom I have created, from the face of the earth—every
> man and beast and crawling creature and bird of the air—for I am
> grieved that I have made them.” Noah, however, found favor in the eyes
> of the LORD.

- Thus, Noah finding grace was because he was prepared to find it and not repudiate divine favor by wicked conduct.  Rom 1:18-22 discusses this same effect; specifically v18-20 says:

> The wrath of God is being revealed from heaven against all the
> godlessness and wickedness of men who suppress the truth by their
> wickedness. For what may be known about God is plain to them, because
> God has made it plain to them. For since the creation of the world
> God’s invisible qualities, His eternal power and divine nature, have
> been clearly seen, being understood from His workmanship, so that men
> are without excuse.

2. God's grace is extended to all people - see appendix 2 below.  Thus, anyone can theoretically find God's grace because people are "without excuse" (Rom 1:20).  However, if people are determined to be sinful, despite the pleadings of divine favor, then they will not "find grace".
3. To "find favor in the eyes of God" is a quintessential Hebraism.  Salvation and grace are the initiative of God alone (Phil 2:13, John 6:44, Rom 2:4) and our response is is due to the prompting of God because repentance is also a gift (Acts 5:31, 11:18, 2 Tim 2:25).  Unfortunately, some reject this gracious gift which Jesus lamented (Matt 23:37, Acts 7:51, 1 Thess 5:19, Eph 4:30), and thus do not "find favor".

Note the text of Heb 4:16 -

> Let us then **approach the throne** of grace with confidence, so that we
> may receive mercy and find grace to help us in our time of need.

Note that we are encourage to "approach the throne" to receive mercy and find favor.  James 4:8 tells us something similar -

> Draw near to God, and He will draw near to you. Cleanse your hands,
> you sinners, and purify your hearts, you double-minded.

Again, we come to God as we are but we must be will to be changed - we do not stay as we are and thus find favor.

**APPENDIX 1 - Toledoths of Genesis**

The book of Genesis is naturally divided into sections, each beginning with a "Toledoth" - a phrase that us usually translated by, "These are the generations of ..."  Each appears to have been written by a different person with the editor of the book (Moses??) writing an introduction which is now Gen 1:1 - 2:3.  These are:

1. Gen 2:4 toledoth of Heavens and Earth
2. Gen 5:1 toledoth of Adam
3. Gen 6:9 toledoth of Noah
4. Gen 10:1 toledoth of Shem Ham and Japheth
5. Gen 11:10 toledoth of Shem
6. Gen 11:27 toledoth of Terah
7. Gen 25:12 toledoth of Ishmael
8. Gen 25:19 toledoth of Isaac
9. Gen 36:1 toledoth of Esau
10. Gen 36:9 toledoth of Esau in Hill Country
11. Gen 37:2 toledoth of Jacob

Each of these is a new section and Gen 6:8 ends and forms a conclusion to the toldeoth of Adam.

**APPENDIX 2 - Divine Grace is Extended to ALL**

Note the following which explicitly speak of universal salvation, and so divine grace, for ALL.

- John 1:29, “Behold the Lamb of God who takes away the sin of the world.”
- John 3:16, “God so loved the world that He gave …”
- John 12:32, “I [Jesus] … will draw all people to myself.”
- John 12;47, “… for I did not come to judge the world but to save the world.”
- Acts 17:30, “God … commands all people everywhere to repent.”
- Rom 3:23, 24, “… for all have sinned … and all are freely forgiven...”
- Rom 5:8, 10, “… while we were still sinners, Christ died for us. … if, while were God’s enemies, we were reconciled to him by the death of His Son, …”
- Rom 5:15, “But the free gift is not like the offense. For if by the one man’s [Adam’s] offense many died, much more the grace of God and the gift by the grace of the one Man, Jesus Christ, abounded to the many.”  [Note the same word, “many” applies to all people.]
- Rom 5:18, “Therefore, as through one man’s offense judgment came to all people, resulting in condemnation, even so through one Man’s righteous act the free gift came to all people, resulting in justification of life.”
- Rom 11:32, “For God has imprisoned everyone in disobedience so that He may show mercy to all.”
- 2 Cor 5:14, “…we are convinced that one died for all, and therefore all died.”
- 2 Cor 5:18, 19, “…God was reconciling the world to Himself in Christ …”
- 1 Tim 2:3, 4, “For this is good and acceptable in the sight of God our Saviour, who desires all men to be saved and to come to the knowledge of the truth.”
- 1 Tim 2:6, “[Jesus Christ] gave Himself as a ransom for all people.”
- Titus 2:11, “For the grace of God appeared bringing salvation to all people.”
- Heb 2:9, “But we see Jesus, who was made a little lower than the angels, now crowned with glory and honour because he suffered death, so that by the grace of God he might taste death for everyone.”
- 2 Peter 3:9, “The Lord is not slow in keeping his promise, as some understand slowness.  He is patient with you, not wanting anyone to perish, but everyone to come to repentance.”
- 1 John 2:2, “He Himself [Jesus] is the propitiation for our sins, and not for ours [Christians to whom John writes] only but also for the whole world.”
- Isa 53:6, “We all like sheep have gone astray … and the LORD has laid on him the iniquity of us all.”

Answer (score 0):

By what means or mechanism did Noah find חן favor/grace in Genesis 6:8?

Noah was different from the people of his days,He was righteous and blameless among his contemporaries. He walked with the true God. How?

Genesis 6:8-9 (NET Bible)

> 8 But[a] Noah found favor[b] in the sight of the Lord.  9 This is the
> account of Noah.Noah was a godly man; he was blameless[e] among his
> contemporaries.

He walked with God. How? By doing the right things, the Apostle Peter ( 2Peter 2:5) wrote that Noah was a  preacher of righteousness and I imagine in a very hostile world.  Also to build the ark that took 40-50 years and in a world in which there was no rain before, he showed great faith and obedience. God did not destroy the righteous with the wicked.

2 Peter 2:5  (NASB)

> 5 And did not spare the ancient world, but protected Noah, a
> [a]preacher of righteousness, with seven others, when He brought a
> flood upon the world of the ungodly;